# PHP-FPM can create slow.log but can`t write content into the slow.log

Tags: php, nginx

Today, I want to enable the slow-logs with **PHP-FPM**, and then I configured some parameters into the `php-fpm.conf`.
In the end, I have a problem, it can create the slow-log, but can't write any contents into the slow-log.
Can someone help me, thanks a lot?

My website is running in Docker, and my **Nginx** use **Unix Sockets** to communicate with **PHP-FPM**, and **Nginx** running as **Root**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm7.sock;
}
```

My `php-fpm.conf` is

```
[www123]
user = app
group = app
listen = /var/run/php-fpm7.sock
listen.owner = app
listen.group = app
listen.mode = 0666

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

slowlog = /app/logs/my_slow_log/$pool.log.slow
request_slowlog_timeout = 1s
```

Next step, I created the directory `app/logs/my_slow_log` and restart the PHP-FPM. It created the file `www123.log.slow` in directory `app/logs/my_slow_log`, but the file permission/user/group is wrong. It was `600 / root / root`

```
/app/logs/my_slow_log # ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    2 app      app             28 May 16 19:32 .
drwxrwxrwx    3 app      app           4096 May 16 19:00 ..
-rw-------    1 root     root             0 May 16 19:32 www123.log.slow
```

There are some running processes

```
app/logs/my_slow_log # ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 runsvdir /etc/service
    7 root       0:00 runsv nginx
    8 root       0:00 runsv javabridge
    9 root       0:00 runsv php7
   10 root       0:00 java -jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/JavaBridge.jar SERVLET_LOCAL:8080
   11 root       0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -g daemon off;
   12 root       0:00 {php-fpm7} php-fpm: master process (/etc/php7/php-fpm.conf)
   13 root       0:00 nginx: worker process
   14 root       0:00 nginx: worker process
   15 root       0:00 nginx: worker process
   16 root       0:00 nginx: worker process
   22 app        0:00 {php-fpm7} php-fpm: pool www123
   23 app        0:00 {php-fpm7} php-fpm: pool www123
```

I find the master php-fpm process was run as **Root**, but the child process was run as **app**, so I modified the `php-fpm.conf` change

```
user = root
group = root
listen.owner = root
listen.group = root
```

then restart PHP-FPM, I got some error message

```
ERROR: [pool www123] please specify user and group other than root
ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

It can't work as **Root**.
I think the problem was `/app/logs/my_slow_log/www123.log.slow` created by PHP-FPM master process with **root**, and my child process was user **app**, so it can't write anything into the slow-log.

I didn't know what truly happened, can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: `chown` the created file to `app:app` after it gets created and check if ti works that way.

Comment: Thank you, I had to try this way in 3 hours ago, use the user Root `chown app:app www123.log.slow | chmod 777 www123.log.slow`.
 It doesn't work, it still can`t write contents into the slow-log.

Comment: Wait, how do you know you can't write any contents to it? Nothing will be written if there's no slow response in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I have to solve this problem, it because of the docker container doesn't have the capability to use `ptrace`,  you need to use  `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE ` with `docker run` to give docker container the capability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command (chmod  777 my_slow_log), I think Log directory permission is not important.

Answer (score 0):

I found that php-fpm will not write anything to the slow log unless the log_level is set to `notice` in `/etc/php-fpm.conf`

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
log_level = notice

While `notice` is the default log_level, I had changed it to `warning` some years ago.  I searched for reasons the slow log wasn't being written, and I didn't see this answer anywhere.  So hopefully it's helpful to someone.